# Tensorflow, gather from image by spatial indices

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a batch of image, `[B, H, W, 3]`, and spatial N indices, `[B, N, 2]`. 2 is for H and W.
Does anyone know how to get N pixels from an image? So the resulting shape is `[B, N, 3]`.
It seems `tf.gather_nd` helps, but I still don't figure out how to. Thank you.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `batch_dims` parameter:

```
params = tf.random.uniform((5, 100, 200, 3))
inds = tf.random.uniform((5, 300, 2), 0, 100, tf.int32)
output = tf.gather_nd(params, inds, batch_dims=1)
```

Comment: Thank you. I confirmed it works perfectly as I expect. You saved my days. Now I understood better how ```batch_dims``` works

Comment: I work on TF1.12 for my job for a library dependency. I found that TF1.12's ```tf.gather_nd``` doesn't have ```batch_dims```. https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/r1.12/site/en/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd.md
Do you know any alternative ways to solve?